# How to create a new Page from a custom Laravel CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel CMS that updates the contents on the frontend. I would like to enable the admin to add new page navigation items on the CMS that gets updated on the Frontend, kindly any clues on how to implement this?

I have checked on tutorials on the same but cannot get the right answer that actually helps to et the job done.

```
Route::get( 'sites/{keyword}', function ( $keyword) {
    fopen( resource_path( 'views/' . $keyword . '.blade.php' ), 'w' );
    return view(  $keyword   );
});
```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing _what_ CMS you're using

Comment: Its a CMS built from scratch.Actually i'm intending to implement the functionality like that provided by wordpress, such that one can be able to create a new page with custom content from the CMS.